# Why is my WordPress plugin not deleting posts after uninstalling?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, uninstallation

I am creating my plugin named ledproperty. I install it and create posts. Then I uninstall my plugin, but after reinstalling it, my old post reappears. I want that after the plugin is removed, everything that was created in the plugin is deleted. How can I fix this?

```
if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN')) exit; 

$ledproperty_args = array('post_type' => 'ledproperty', 'posts_per_page' => -1); 
$ledproperty_posts = get_posts($ledproperty_args); 

foreach ($ledproperty_posts as $post) { 
   wp_delete_post($post->ID, false); 
}
```

Comment: <?php 
if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN')) exit;


$ledproperty_args = array('post_type' => 'ledproperty', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$ledproperty_posts = get_posts($ledproperty_args);
foreach ($ledproperty_posts as $post) {
   wp_delete_post($post->ID, false);
}

Comment: Please show code in the question, properly formatted, not in comments where it is hard to read.

Comment: You are checking old post in trash or publish status?

Comment: No. I just uninstall the plugin and then install again. And the previously created posts remain there. I want them to automatically disappear when the plugin is uninstalled

Comment: My post in  publish status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute some code after deactivating your plugin, you need to use the function register_deactivation_hook():

```
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'ledproperty_plugin_deactivation');
function ledproperty_plugin_deactivation() {
    $ledproperty_args = array('post_type' => 'ledproperty', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any');
    $ledproperty_posts = get_posts($ledproperty_args);

    foreach ($ledproperty_posts as $post) {
        wp_delete_post($post->ID, false);
    }
}
```

Additionally, I recommend adding **'post_status' => 'any'** to the args.